# unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 991

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, wordpress

I have a wordpress site locally and I am trying to build it's hybrid app using `AngularJS`.

In wordpress, I created a plugin to fetch data.
I get the metadata in the form of `array` as

```
Array
(
[REAL_HOMES_gallery_slider_type] => Array
    (
        [0] => thumb-on-right
    )

[REAL_HOMES_property_images] => Array
    (
        [0] => 94
    )

[REAL_HOMES_property_price] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3850
    )

[REAL_HOMES_property_size] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2800
    )

[REAL_HOMES_property_bedrooms] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
    )

[REAL_HOMES_property_bathrooms] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[REAL_HOMES_property_garage] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[REAL_HOMES_property_address] => Array
    (
        [0] => Athwa Gate, Surat, Gujarat 395008, India
    )

[REAL_HOMES_property_location] => Array
    (
        [0] => 21.1852392,72.80947859999992
    )

[REAL_HOMES_tour_video_url] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://vimeo.com/70301553
    )

[REAL_HOMES_featured] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[REAL_HOMES_add_in_slider] => Array
    (
        [0] => no
    )

[REAL_HOMES_agents] => Array
    (
        [0] => 110
    )

[_dp_original] => Array
    (
        [0] => 75
    )

[REAL_HOMES_property_price_postfix] => Array
    (
        [0] => Per Month
    )

[_wp_old_slug] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15421-southwest-39th-terrace-fl
    )

[REAL_HOMES_tour_video_image] => Array
    (
        [0] => 94
    )

[REAL_HOMES_property_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => Aagam003
    )

[REAL_HOMES_property_size_postfix] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sq Ft
    )

[slide_template] => Array
    (
        [0] => default
    )

[REAL_HOMES_agent_display_option] => Array
    (
        [0] => agent_info
    )

[_edit_lock] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1436890564:1
    )

[_edit_last] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[_thumbnail_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 894
    )

[REAL_HOMES_slider_image] => Array
    (
        [0] => 841
    )

)
```

so I converted it to a simple `array` and got the bellow `array`.

```
Array
(
[REAL_HOMES_gallery_slider_type] => thumb-on-right
[REAL_HOMES_property_images] => 94
[REAL_HOMES_property_price] => 3850
[REAL_HOMES_property_size] => 2800
[REAL_HOMES_property_bedrooms] => 2
[REAL_HOMES_property_bathrooms] => 1
[REAL_HOMES_property_garage] => 1
[REAL_HOMES_property_address] => Athwa Gate, Surat, Gujarat 395008, India
[REAL_HOMES_property_location] => 21.1852392,72.80947859999992
[REAL_HOMES_tour_video_url] => http://vimeo.com/70301553
[REAL_HOMES_featured] => 1
[REAL_HOMES_add_in_slider] => no
[REAL_HOMES_agents] => 110
[_dp_original] => 75
[REAL_HOMES_property_price_postfix] => Per Month
[_wp_old_slug] => 15421-southwest-39th-terrace-fl
[REAL_HOMES_tour_video_image] => 94
[REAL_HOMES_property_id] => Aagam003
[REAL_HOMES_property_size_postfix] => Sq Ft
[slide_template] => default
[REAL_HOMES_agent_display_option] => agent_info
[_edit_lock] => 1436890564:1
[_edit_last] => 1
[_thumbnail_id] => 894
[REAL_HOMES_slider_image] => 841
)
```

Ihen I encoded this `array` to Json using Php.

```
json_encode($result);
```

$result is the resultant array

I called an Ajax request using AngularJS and the response gave me result just below.

```
{"REAL_HOMES_gallery_slider_type":"thumb-on-right","REAL_HOMES_property_images":"94","REAL_HOMES_property_price":"3850","REAL_HOMES_property_size":"2800","REAL_HOMES_property_bedrooms":"2","REAL_HOMES_property_bathrooms":"1","REAL_HOMES_property_garage":"1","REAL_HOMES_property_address":"Athwa Gate, Surat, Gujarat 395008, India","REAL_HOMES_property_location":"21.1852392,72.80947859999992","REAL_HOMES_tour_video_url":"http:\/\/vimeo.com\/70301553","REAL_HOMES_featured":"1","REAL_HOMES_add_in_slider":"no","REAL_HOMES_agents":"110","_dp_original":"75","REAL_HOMES_property_price_postfix":"Per Month","_wp_old_slug":"15421-southwest-39th-terrace-fl","REAL_HOMES_tour_video_image":"94","REAL_HOMES_property_id":"Aagam003","REAL_HOMES_property_size_postfix":"Sq Ft","slide_template":"default","REAL_HOMES_agent_display_option":"agent_info","_edit_lock":"1436890564:1","_edit_last":"1","_thumbnail_id":"894","REAL_HOMES_slider_image":"841"}0
```

I dont know why there is a zero at the end even if I had not appended anything with the response.
I guess the result is a Json string so i tried converting this to Json object to use it and fetch data from the keys.
I have other Json responses which are in `[]` brackets. but this one is not, may be due to the 0 at the end of the Json string response.

Please help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: You must to show your code, but it seems that in PHP page there are a `0` writted in document and this is not relative to the JSON compilance. If you show us the code we can see better

Comment: i managed to remove the 0 at the end of json string by adding die();

Comment: the zero was removed by using the die(); after the output was converted to json and i was able to fetch it in the html using angularjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a thing with wordpress and its ajax system. If you look at the file [wp-admin/admin-ajax.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php), at the end of the file there's a die(0) statement which is the culprit.

In order for that statement not to be run, you need to add a wp_die(); statement after you output your JSON string (this is in the [wordpress documentation on ajax requests](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)).

Comment: If this really is the case, it should be reported as bug to Wordpress.

Comment: @Tigger updated with reference to the WP source, this is the default behaviour of the ajax system, the zero is supposed to show that the ajax endpoint hasn't been configured

Comment: but for your info only; other ajax requests work perfect.

Comment: @RanjankumarSahoo it's probably because those endpoints are terminated correctly, I've added a new reference to the official wordpress documentation on the subject of working with ajax and wp.

Comment: now i get this error unexpected character at line 1 column 2